# How to set Amazon S3 bucket presigned URL expiration time in 1 year from current date

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Images are uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket. I need to get a **presigned URL** from Amazon server. Also I want to set the expiry time of that URL. That can take only maximum of 17 days. But I can't set maximum of 1 year expiration time.

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        Date nextYear = cal.getTime();

    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
                "bucketName", "accessname");
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        generatePresignedUrlRequest
                .setExpiration(nextYear);
        URL url = s3client
                .generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
        bucketURL = url.toString();
```

Comment: TL:DR - v4 signing algo allows only 7 days. (Regarding v4 from the docs: This latest signature version is supported in all regions and any new regions after January 30, 2014 will support only Signature Version 4.)  So, you are better off generating the presigned url when required.

Answer (score 20):

You do not "get" a pre-signed URL "from server."  Signature calculation is done on the client.  Pre-signed URLs are actually calculated on your machine, not by the service.

If you are using a current SDK, it is probably using Signature V4.  If the signed URL includes `X-Amz-Signature=` then this confirms V4.  The older V2 algorithm only uses `Signature=` in a signed URL.

If your signature is indeed V4, then you are seeing an intentional limitation:

> A presigned URL can be valid for a maximum of seven days because the signing key you use in signature calculation is valid for up to seven days.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

If you are already using V2, you should be able to sign URLs with expiration times as late as the year 2038.  If you are using V4, you could work around the limitation by switching to use V2, but this is not advisable.  V2 is not supported in newer S3 regions, like Frankfurt, and if you rotate your AWS access keys like you should, the eventual key invalidation will also invalidate any signatures created with that key.

The more correct approach in most cases is to generate the signed URL when you need it.  That operation, as noted, requires no interaction with the S3 service and can typically be done in real time.

If you need to give a specific user access to a "direct link," consider creating an endpoint in your application where the user's credentials can be evaluated, at which point you can generate a signed URL and redirect the browser with an HTTP `302` response.

Comment: How can I switch to V2? Is there a global property for it?

Comment: V2 doesn't work in newer regions, @Ruslan, and since V4 is in most ways a far-better algorithm, I don't know if that's possible any more, but it probably is.  What region are you working in, and what SDK are you using?  Something I should have thought to mentiom in this answer is CloudFront.  CloudFront uses a different authentication mechanism than S3 but can be used in front of any Bucket.  CloudFront signed URLs are not limited to short time intervals, and have two options S3 doesn't -- you can limit a signed URL to being used from a single IP address, and you can set start-valid time also.

Comment: I'm in an old region I guess. Thanks for the answer, but I have already found a solution:-) clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType")