# S3 link with longer expiration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am generating a pre-signed link using the java sdk for a client. We have new requirements to allow the links to remain active for at least 30 days. When I set the expiration longer I get the below error:

> Requests that are pre-signed by SigV4 algorithm are valid for at most
>   7 days

I need to determine a way around this as the client cannot accept updates to the links (say, if I just auto-generated updates weekly). Is there a way around this? Can I pass a given set of read-only creds maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33016395/1428388) for a description of the limitation on the days.

Generating read only credentials for the client would not work well because the client would have to use those credentials to either create their own pre-signed URL (no different than you doing it now -- it will still expire in a max of 7 days) or use an AWS SDK to directly download the file without a pre-signed URL.

Using SigV4 and having a constant link for longer than 7 days could be done with a middle layer (like a REST endpoint) whose URL does not change and serves up the file when requested.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details about how to solve the expiration problem of signed URL with a middle layer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Using S3 pre-signed urls unfortunately is not possible to go beyond the 7 days.

One possible solution is to **use CloudFront signed urls**, these don't have a "limit" on how long the urls can be valid. S3 bucket will still remain private.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Java Example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CFPrivateDistJavaDevelopment.html

Comment: They are 2 more options for anyone who is looking to achieve this documented in my comment. https://medium.com/@django.course/to-avoid-the-limitation-of-7-day-window-for-pre-signed-urls-as-mentioned-by-bryant-biggs-e921da4ea96e and below reference code

Answer (score -1):

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from botocore.client import Config

# python > 3 should be installed
# pip install boto3
# s3v4
# (Default) Signature Version 4
# v4 algorithm starts with X-Amz-Algorithm
#
# s3
# (Deprecated) Signature Version 2,  this only works in some regions new regions not supported
# if you have to generate signed url that has > 7 days expiry then use version 2 if your region supports it. below code illustration of this

s3_signature ={
    'v4':'s3v4',
    'v2':'s3'
}

def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, bucket_key, expiration=3600):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param bucket_key: string
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the presigned URL to remain valid
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """

    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id='your_access_key_here',
                             aws_secret_access_key='your_secret_key_here',
                             config=Config(signature_version=s3_signature['v2']),
                             region_name='us-east-1'
                             )
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': bucket_key},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response

weeks = 8

seven_days_as_seconds = 604800

signed_url = create_presigned_url('your_bucket_here', 'your_key/file_name.xls', (seven_days_as_seconds*weeks))

print(signed_url)
```